# Configure Postgresql sslrootcert with Spring Cloud Connectors & HikariCP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, postgresql-9.6, spring-cloud-connectors

I'm currently trying to setup a datasource (Postgresql) on my SpringBoot 2.1.1 application with Spring Cloud Connectors (my application is hosted on PCF).
I need to configure the path to my sslrootcert (which is not specified in the jdbc url provided by the service broker we are using on PCF).

I've tried to configure it that way :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig = new DataSourceConfig(null, new DataSourceConfig.ConnectionConfig("sslrootcert=/home/vcap/app/.postgresql/root.crt"), Collections.singletonMap("sslrootcert", "/home/vcap/app/.postgresql/root.crt"));
    return connectionFactory().dataSource(dataSourceConfig);
}
```

but my sslrootcert property is always ignored and fall back to the default ~/.postgresql/root.crt

I can't find anything in the documentation regarding a way of setting this kind of driver specific property.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the `sslrootcert` value typically passed to Postgres? Is it part of the JDBC URL? Can you provide an example of what you expect Postgres to get?

Comment: Either in the url (for example jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db?ssl=true&sslrootcert=/path/to/root/cert) or as a property on the driver :

`String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("sslrootcert","/path/to/root/cert");
props.setProperty("ssl","true");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);`